# Hyperledger Composer Rest Server Query from WebApp

Tags: api, hyperledger-composer

i am developing a front end application using html and javascript for interaction with locally deployed hyperledger composer rest server. I have been able to use Get method to list all the assets that have been already created. But now i am trying to use a search query for a specific asset. And i have created a separate file for testing purposes for that query.

This is the code thus far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnGetCheque').click(function () {
                var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
                resultElement.html('');

                var requestData = $('#txtNumber').val() ;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/queries/ChequeByNumber',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {Cheque_Number:requestData},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.message != null) {
                            resultElement.html(response.message);
                        }
                        else {
                            resultElement.html('Cheque: ' + response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtNumber" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="button" id="btnGetCheque" value="Get Cheque Data">
    <br /><br />
    <div id="resultDiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it produces following error. 
[It produces this dialog box on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYdjc.png)

And there is nothing on console log, it is empty.

**EDIT**

This is the business model file

```
namespace org.acme.chequebook

asset Cheque identified by chequeNumber {

o String chequeNumber

}
```

And this is the query.qy file

```
 query ChequeByNumber {
   description: "Returns a cheque in the registry"
   statement:  
      SELECT  org.acme.chequebook.Cheque
      WHERE   (chequeNumber == _$Cheque_Number)
  } 
query AllCheques {
   description: "Returns all cheques in the registry"
   statement:  
      SELECT  org.acme.chequebook.Cheque
 }
```

This is api url if i search a specific cheque from rest api

```
http://localhost:3000/api/queries/ChequeByNumber?Cheque_Number=12345
```

Comment: you should post both your model definition and also the queries.qry file where you've defined the query endpoint, thanks.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working with `Cheque_Number` , user tested it by changing datatype and then changing it back to json and now it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks but when i replace **Cheque_Number** with **chequeNumber** , it produces following error  **GEThttp://localhost:3000/api/queries/ChequeByNumber?chequeNumber=12345 400 (Bad Request)**

Comment: It's working now but with **Cheque_Number** , i tested it by changing datatype and then changing it back to **json** and now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: cool, I've updated the answer with yours - you are correct, it should be Cheque_Number in your `data:` section